# Symfony's Gedmo Tree throws sorting error

Tags: symfony

Following Gedmo Tree manual I'd like to get tree of categories like the documentation shows:

`$repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Category::class); $tree = $repository->childrenHierarchy();`

however it throws an exception:

`Invalid sort options specified: field - root, direction - asc`

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Fix 2486 doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I faced [the same issue](https://github.com/doctrine-extensions/DoctrineExtensions/issues/2508) and had to rollback the gedmo/doctrine-extensions version 3.7.